# How can I get distances from Google maps javascript api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, closures

I'm trying to sort through an array of distances generated by google maps.  I need to order my list, closest to furthest.  I can get all of the directions and distances displayed just fine with the directionsService api example, but I cannot figure out how to retrieve that info outside of the function so that I can sort it.

```
    function calcDistances() {
    for (var x = 0; x < wineries.length; x++) {
        var winery = wineries[x];
        var trdistances = [];       
        var request = {
            origin: map.getCenter(), 
            destination: new google.maps.LatLng(winery[1], winery[2]),
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                var route = response.routes[0];
                var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("tasting_rooms_panel");
                // For each route, display summary information.
                for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                    //this works fine and displays properly
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text;
                    //I want to store to this array so that I can sort
                    trdistances.push(route.legs[i].distance.text);
                }
            }
        });
        alert(trdistances[0]);//debug
    }
}
```

As commented in the code, I can populate summaryPanel.innerHTML, but when I populate the array trdistances, the alert gives me "undefined".  Is this some rookie javascript coding error?  I read up on the scope of variables and this should work. Help me oh wise ones.

Comment: try `alert(trdistances[0]);//debug` after the for loop within `directionsService.route`

Comment: Thanks kj.  Yes, I've tried that and it works.  My problem is that I need to access the info after the loop, that's why the debug alert is where it is.  Once this loop is run, I want to order wineries by their distance from the users location.

Comment: you can create a function on global scope that gets called within the callback function of route, and do the logic there. the reason when u do `alert(trdistances[0])` and gets nothing is because the callback function hasn't been invoked yet and thus, there's nothing in `trdistances[0]` so you want to invoke the logic after the callback is return.

Comment: Kjy, I think you're right.  I'm exploring that right now, but I'm still having a problem getting the info back from the function.  Can you show me an example that I can try out?  Thanks

Comment: @Poolczar sure give me a sec while i formulate a small example

Comment: @Poolczar take a look at my answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function calcDistances() {
    for (var x = 0; x < wineries.length; x++) {
        var winery = wineries[x];
        var trdistances = [];       
        var request = {
            origin: map.getCenter(), 
            destination: new google.maps.LatLng(winery[1], winery[2]),
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        //Using Closure to get the right X and store it in index
        (function(index){
               directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                         var route = response.routes[0];
                         var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("tasting_rooms_panel");
                         // For each route, display summary information.
                         for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                              //this works fine and displays properly
                              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text;
                              //I want to store to this array so that I can sort
                              trdistances.push(route.legs[i].distance.text);
                         }

                         if(index == wineries.length-1){  //check to see if this is the last x callback
                              console.log(trdistances); //this should print the result 
                              //or in your case you can create  global function that gets called here like sortMahDistance(trdistances); where the function does what you want.
                              printMyDistances(trdistances); //calls global function and prints out content of trdistances console.log();
                         }
                    }
               });
        })(x);  //pass x into closure as index
    }
}

//on global scope
function printMyDistances(myArray){
     console.log(myArray);
}
```

The problem is scope to keep track of the for loop's `X`.  Basically, you have to make sure all the callbacks are done before you can get the final result of trdistances.  So, you'll have to use closure to achieve this.  By storing first for loops' `X` into `index` within closure by passing `X` in as `index`, you can check to see if the callback is the last one, and if it is then your `trdistances` should be your final result.  This mod of your code should work, but if not please leave comment.

Furthermore, I marked up my own version of google map using closure to resolve using async directionServices within for loop, and it worked.  Here is my demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/UD6jb/).  Trace the output of `console.log();` to see `X` vs `index` within the closure.

Comment: I still don't have access to trdistances outside of the function.  It doesn't even need to be trdistances, it could be another element in wineries.  Currently, wineries has a winery name, lat an long.  Using lat and long, I'm calculating the distance from the user via the directions service.  Once all those are complete, I need to order the whole array by distance so that I can display "closest winery 'Bubbly bubbles' is .5 km from where you are standing".

Comment: make `trdistances` global by declaring it outside of all functions.  as of now it is inside of the `calcDistances` unless you create a global function to access it and pass `trdistances` as parameter into it.  Take a look at my jsfiddle and see how i set up the variables

Comment: @Poolczar keep in mind you want to access the `trdistances` or which ever var you are storing it in mind it be `trdistances` or `wineries` you must wait until the callback functions all return

Comment: Your genius. Sorry for the confusion, the first time I ran it, something didn't work right.  I think my apache server was lobotomized.  A reboot and a quick comb through on the code and it's working.  Thanks